# скормить массив с url-ами изображений в <img class>

Tags: python, django

Вот тут я получил нужные урлы

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def main(request):
    return render(request,'main.html')

req = requests.get('https://d3.ru/api/posts').json()
arr = []
for data in req['posts']:
    urls = data['main_image_url']
    if urls != None:
        arr.append(urls)
print('urls',arr)
```

как мне скормить `arr` в мой шаблон

```
{% extends "wrapper.html" %}
{% block title %}
<div class="container">
    <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src=///arr???>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Понимаю, что нужно прогнать это через loop, но не знаю как)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передать список в шаблон.

К примеру так: 
`return render(request, 'путь к шаблону.html', {"arr": arr})`

Тогда в шаблоне он будет вам доступен как `{{arr}}`.
А дальше уже циклом парсите.

Comment: спасибо. теперь буду знать